# FaceTime audio when blocked?

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

If you're blocked as a contact on a iPhone can you still contact them by FaceTime audio?

Answer (score 1):

No. Blocking a number will block it for normal calls, FaceTime and FaceTime audio.

You might have to pay attention to the details though to fully block someone. Anyone using FaceTime has an AppleID so you'd want to block the Apple ID (usually it's an email) and possibly also block the associated cellular number(s) since you can attach several phone numbers to one Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

If the blocking person has done following then NO, you can not contact them:

[Block phone numbers and contacts on your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5845)

> You will not receive phone calls, messages, or FaceTime calls from people on your block list. There are many ways to add people to your block list; choose any one of the following:
>
> In the FaceTime or Phone app, you can go to Favorites or Recents:
>
> 1. Tap the Info button next to the name or number you wish to block.
> 2. Scroll to the bottom of the card and tap Block this Caller.
> 3. Tap Block Contact.
>
> In the FaceTime or Phone app, you can also tap the Contacts button:
>
> 1. Tap the contact you wish to block.
> 2. Scroll to the bottom of the card and tap Block this Caller.
> 3. Tap Block Contact.
>
> In the Messages app:
>
> 1. Tap the message from the individual you wish to block.
> 2. Tap Contact in the upper right.
> 3. Tap the Info button, directly under the Done button.  If it is a group  message, select the appropriate button for the individual you wish to block.
> 4. Scroll to the bottom of the card and tap Block this Caller.
> 5. Tap Block Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can still receive facetime audio from blocked callers. I have a contact blocked on my daughter's phone and it still rang through in facetime and facetime audio.

Comment: I'll expand upon George's answer, but this might depend on your definition of "block" - when you block a phone number, that won't block an email/AppleID so if someone is blocked, nothing stops them from making another Apple ID and then calling you again. You need to block both the account and the mobile number - perhaps multiple of the above if someone makes a new account once blocked.

Answer (score -2):

Yes they can bc the kid that blocked me called me

Comment: You would have to block them to keep them from calling you. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140759/5472 for details on what you need to do to really block several aspects of one FaceTime contact.